# Find a file from a partial filename in python

Tags: python, file, search, directory, filenames

I am looking for a python script that will find the the exact filename of an existing file in the current directory that this python script will run from, that may be named incrementally.

For example the file could be:
`file1.dat`
`file2.dat`
`file3.dat`
....

So we know that the file name starts with the prefix `file` and we know that it ends with the sufix `.dat`.

But we don't know whether it will be `file1.dat` or `file1000.dat` or anything inbetween.

So I need a script that will check in the range of say `1-1000` all filenames from `file1.dat` to `file1000.dat`, and if it finds the one that does exist in the directory, it returns a success message.

Comment: Maybe take a look to the module `glob`

Comment: have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range(1, 1001):
    if os.path.isfile("file{0}.dat".format(i)):
        print("Success!")
        break
else:
    print("Failure!")
```

Answer (score 8):

Try something like this:

```
import os

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

for f_name in os.listdir(path):
    if f_name.startswith('file') and f_name.endswith('.dat'):
        print('found a match')
```

Comment: This has the possibility of matching files with names like `file-sample.dat` or `file.dat`.

Comment: @ZachGates Yes, it does. This was just meant to be a starting point. I'm 100% sure what his naming convention is/will be.

Answer (score 4):

I would search with a regex using Python's [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module. Here's a sample expression:

```
glob.glob(r'^file(\d+)\.dat$')
```

This will match a filename starting with `file`, followed by any digits, and ending with `.dat`. For a deeper explanation on how this regex works, check it out on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6JM4vB/1), where you can test it, as well.

Note: Your question did not specify, but as a bonus, `glob` also supports recursive searches.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested in comments, glob and other options are available,however, personally i find listdir more comfortable.

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("/DIRECTORY"):
    if file.endswith(".dat") and prefix in file:
        print file
```

Comment: What is `prefix`? I suspect it's `"file"`, and if that is the case, you could end up matching files like `file-sample.dat`, etc. Using the `in` operator, you could even match files like `sample-file.dat` or `ignore-this-file.dat`.